# Marking config file as 'Permanent'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

How can I mark my application config file as 'Permanent' so that it is not removed/overwritten during uninstall or upgrade? The 'Permanent' property appears to work with *File System* level objects only, whereas the config file appears as one of the *outputs* of my *Primary Project Output* object, which if marked Permanent, would prevent the EXE file from being removed as well.

I'm using standard Windows Installer project that ships with VS2010 and the application type is WinForms desktop app.

Comment: Using "Project Output" to select files is a convenience but not the only way.  You can also use "File" to pick individual files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Christoper, that, maybe your are not aware of, there is no need to conserve potential user settings changes in case of an update. Or in other words, if your file is changed after installation, no msi update will change it *ever* (but uninstall/removal works).

But you are talking about protecting this file from removal by uninstall.
One the one hand you could try to mark it as permanent, maybe the other answer of picking it, helps there. I don't like and know that tool much.

But here is the good architectural pattern **How to manage settings in a setup**:

- A setup should be uninstalled completely including the setting file. But see it only as the "setup"-default, not the current configuration.
- Maybe you decide, your configuration is user dependent, this is much easier to handle in the application itself than in the setup.

  1. Start a special config action/function in your app, (not in your setup) when the program starts.
  2. In this function first read in the config file (or registry values) installed by the setup as a (mostly machine-level) default configuration.
  3. Now persist in your app the actual configuration to a file, e.g. as a user-dependent .config file (somewhere in the %USERPROFILE% as in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local)
     Of course you can use also %ProgramData% for machine-level or the registry (HKCU or HKLM).
     But now this is the *actual* configuration, not the default one.

=> And because the setup does not know about this actual configuration (file), it will not uninstall it nor modify it, only you can do it in your app.

=> This "pattern" allows an extension to leverage settings format, e.g. adding new settings in version 2.0, and to import old setting format V1.0 in your app. Or otherwise, simpler, ignore old settings in version 2.0.

An alternative would be to do the duplication in a user-specific part of the MSI setup, e.g. by using "DuplicateFiles" but I would not recommend such advanced things like user-dependant setup resources neither for a setup beginner nor with Visual Studio. There is no need to do this in the setup, and my pattern above gives more flexibility and safety.

Comment: Hmm...I see what you're suggesting. One downside that I can see is that I'll probably then be missing the development-time support that is provided by VS for the default settings file. I can bind my controls directly to a setting, which loads/saves the values automatically for me. Using a different setting file will kill that feature, yes?

Comment: You can use as many setting files as you like. If you want to have only one myapp.exe.config saving also things like background color, what is quite uncommon, you though could deliver in the setup a myapp.exe.setupdefault.config and read this the first time the app is started (e.g. for each user). There are a number of possibilities. And you can include the myapp.exe.config in your setup or not. I think, it is more powerful, if not, but it dependes on your strategy, if settings shall survive uninstalls. But to support user-specific settings in general you need more than one setting file e.g.

Comment: The most simple solution is to mark you single setting file (more precise, it's MSI component) as permanent, then your setting survives uninstall. Not so powerful as my pattern, but maybe sufficient for you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't see a valid requirement here.  Under the default file versioning rules, if the config file has been modified since installation it now contains user data and will by default not be removed.  It will also by default not be overwritten during a subsequent transaction because it contains user data.  The real problem I typically see is when a newer version of the software has a different schema and you need to get the latest schema and the user data.  MSI doesn't do this will and the solution is usually 2 config files.  One owned by the installer and one owned by the app.